# Complex ModelComponent on RealityKit Entity

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to use RealityKits Entity Component system to it's fullest extent but I'm having trouble fitting together a few pieces. Specifically around the `HasModel` Component.

In Reality Composer I make a simple model composed of three basic objects. I export it as a `.USDZ` file and drop it into my Xcode project.

[image]

I then load the model from disk like this:

```swift
guard let basicLabelFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "label", withExtension: "usdz") else {
    fatalError("Could not find label file")
}
let basicLabel = try ModelEntity.loadModel(contentsOf: basicLabelFileURL)
```

I then have custom Entity called `LabelEntity`

```swift
class LabelEntity: Entity, HasAnchoring, HasModel {
    
    required public init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    public init(entity: Entity) {
        super.init()
        self.model = ??? entity?
    }
}
```

Which gets Initialized with the model from disk.

```swift
let newLabelEntity = LabelEntity(entity: basicLabel)
```

As you can see I wan't to make the model loaded from disk the `ModelComponent` of my Custom Entity. However the [`ModelComponent` initalizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/modelcomponent/init(mesh:materials:)) only accepts a single mesh and then array of material.

Where is my knowledge gap? How can I make a custom Entity using the ModelComponent from a complex hierarchy of meshes (other models)?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'd really like to know the answer too!

Answer (score 2):

I just ended up adding the loaded model as a child entity to the "wrapper" entity. However, we ran into a similar problem when trying to modify (change material) of an entity loaded from disk. Here are some extension on `Entity`

```swift
xtension Entity {
    func explore(children: Entity.ChildCollection) {
        for (index, child) in children.enumerated() {
            print("\(index), \(child.components.self)")
            self.explore(children: child.children)
        }
    }
    
    
    func findChild<T>(entity: Entity? = nil, name: String? = nil, type: T.Type) -> T? {
        let children = findChildren(entity: entity, name: name)
        for child in children {
            if let castChild = child as? T {
                return castChild
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    
    func findChildren(entity: Entity? = nil, name: String? = nil) -> [Entity] {
        let target = entity ?? self
        
        var foundChildren: [Entity] = []
        if (target.name == name) || (name == nil) {
            foundChildren.append(target)
        }
        
        for child in target.children {
            foundChildren = foundChildren + findChildren(entity: child, name: name)
        }
        
        return foundChildren
    }
}
```

Untested but if you get the first child of the loaded model which conforms to `HasModel` like this

```swift
let myLoadedEntity: Entity = <Loaded from disk>

let firstModelEntity = myLoadedEntity.self.findChild(type: ModelEntity.self).first

let myCustomModelEntity: HasModel = <construct custom entity>

myCustomEntity.model = firstModelEntity?.model
```

Note that the extension let you find a layer of your loaded entity by name. If you know it then you can search for it directly with the extension.

Assuming this works you still might have to work with the designer of the asset to get the layers right.

Comment: I'll use that as a workaround, but it seems to defeat the purpose of the whole Entity Component System structure they've got going. Now we're creating child entities, rather than actually just using the Entity with the correct components on it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, though. I'll leave the bounty up to see if anyone has a way to actually make the one Entity have all the components it needs. If not, I'll award yours at the end.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code to help parse a ModelComponent out of the loaded entity.

Comment: I tried both adding it as a child & swapping the ModelComponent, however, the created ModelEntity doesn't have a ModelComponent. It seems far more complicated, the `Entity.load(contentsOf: url)` seems to build a whole tree, with the ModelComponents further down the tree. It seems like your first suggestion of adding the model as a child is the correct way to do it.